# Dealing with the message "unknown flag: --build-arg" with docker run

Tags: docker, dockerfile

The next cmd returns the error:  `unknown flag: --build-arg`
Why?

```
docker run --name=my_dev_server --network=host --privileged \
     -v /dev:/dev \
       --build-arg USERNAME=`${USER}` \
       --user=`id -u ${USER}` \
       --env="DISPLAY" \
       --volume="/etc/group:/etc/group:ro" \
       --volume="/etc/passwd:/etc/passwd:ro" \
       --volume="/etc/shadow:/etc/shadow:ro" \
       --volume="/etc/sudoers.d:/etc/sudoers.d:ro" \
       --volume="/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix:rw" \
      -it jccz/android_dev:v1 /bin/bash
```

Comment: because `--build-arg` is for `build`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `--build-arg` option for [`run`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#options), it's available only for [`build`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/#options)